# saving prefilled inputs in vue

Tags: javascript, input, vue.js, autofill

I'm build a rather extensive form and I'm trying to make sure that users won't lose their data on simple browser reload. Fortunately, browsers nowadays refill data on a reload - and, indeed, inputs with `v-model` have it during `beforeMount`. The problem is, they lose it on `mounted`, because they get filled with data from the respective model which is, reasonably enough, empty.
Now, I suppose I could fill the model on `beforeMounted` with data extracted from DOM - but can I somehow get the reference of a `v-model` hooked to the object from DOM? Or maybe is there some other way you would do it?

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you're creating a user, so you have the user model defined in your component as

```
data () {
  return {
    user: {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }
}
```

And your input element like `<input type="email" v-model.lazy="user.email" />` (notice the [**lazy**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy) modifier, for my example, I recommend you to use it, for performance purposes).

Now, you can set up a **watcher** for the `user` model that stores its values in `sessionStorage` (my choice, you can use localStorage instead).
Read the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

in your component:

```
watch: {
  user (newValues, oldValues) {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(newValues))
  }
}
```

And now, just be sure you load the values before you mount the component

```
created () { // created hook
  let userData = window.sessionStorage.getItem('userData')

  if (userData) {
    try {
      userData = JSON.parse(userData)

      // now initiate the model
      this.user.email = userData.email
      this.user.password = userData.password
    } catch (err) {
      // userData was not a valid json string
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this gave me an idea for saving data outside vue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I really want to leverage browser built-in capabilities for this - especially that with this simple trick I can use it in a global mixin/plugin and it's data structure agnostic. I save all  required information in DOM and re-update the DOM after `mounted` is called.

```
export default {
    beforeMount() {
        document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((el) => {
            if (el.value) {
                el.setAttribute('data-prefill', el.value)
            }
        })
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$el.querySelectorAll('[data-prefill]').forEach((el) => {
            this.$nextTick(function() {
                el.value = el.getAttribute('data-prefill')
                el.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
                el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Some things on this: 1) The input values set on element attributes are not persistent if the page is refreshed (F5). 2) Some input elements may not be rendered yet when using conditional rendering. 3) Because of (2), you now rely on `dispatchEvent`, which should be avoided and use element references (`ref`) instead. I strongly suggest the watcher approach for this, which can be implemented as a component mixin as well.